# How to convert json string to methodinfo parameter?

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, casting, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a `json` string to a `MethodInfo` parameter type. I have the followings:

```
Type type = typeof(MyClass);
MethodInfo mi = type.GetMethod(myMethod);
ParameterInfo [] parameteres=mi.GetParameters();
var jsonString="{\"LastName\":\"Test\"}"
```

Using these codes I have the input type of `mymethod` and it is a class containing a property named `LastName` (the class name is `Class1`).

Now how to convert `jsonString` to `Class1`.

Hint: We get the type `Class1` in run time.

Comment: you can parse JSON into another object and send it as function parameter

Comment: DeserializeObject has different method overloading for none-generic for  accepting a type.youcan see Overload List here https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm

Comment: @styx You were right. please post it as an answer so that I choose it as correct answer.

Comment: @HamidReza do need to use reflection? because **TemaTre** answer is quite good

Comment: @styx That did not work for me because it was creating instance dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

So, ParameterInfo calss has it own property ParameterType.
You should get this parameter and some lib to working with Json like this
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Then code will be like

```
Type type = typeof(MyClass);
MethodInfo mi = type.GetMethod(myMethod);
ParameterInfo [] parameteres=mi.GetParameters();
ParameterInfo myParameter = parameteres.FirstOrDefault();

var jsonString="{\"LastName\":\"Test\"}"
var myObjParameter = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString, myParameter.ParameterType );

//Then create an objevt of main class.
ConstructorInfo constr = type .GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
object classInstance = constr.Invoke(new object[]{});

//And call method for this object
mi .Invoke(classInstance , new object[]{ myObjParameter });
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your class looks like this

```
        public class MyClass
        {
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            private void myMethod(string LastName)
            {
                //do sutff
            }
        }
```

you can simply deserialize string like this(you can use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json))

```
   var jsonString = "{\"LastName\":\"Test\"}";
   var lastName = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(jsonString);
```

now you can use `lastName` as you wish dynamically or statically